# Dynamic memory allocation...how about this type of inititlization?

Tags: c++

To create an integer on heap and initialize it to a value 5, we do:

```
int* a = new int(5);
```

To create an array of 5 integers on the heap, we do:

```
int* a = new int[5];
```

But, if we want to create an array of 5 integers and initialize each of them to 10 in one single instruction, is it possible?

**To make things more interesting, let us say that the array size will only be known at run time. How about then?**

Also, I know this is a very trivial question, but I'm making this transition from Java and get confused at times with C++, so... if not initialized during declaration, then unlike in Java, C++ primitive data types are not initialized with default values, and contain garbage values, right?

But someone told me that if they are declared as global variables, then they are initialized to default values like in Java...is that true as well? Why?

Comment: Still using raw pointers i see :)

Comment: You can make no assumption about the default values of "plain old data" types (int, double, char, etc)

Comment: @ rmccabe3701: Haha, I was just going through my previous code and wanted to get a clarification on this. In the future, I will be using vectors. It's my instructor, you know. He doesn't encourage using vectors.

Comment: I would recommend spending some quality time with these lectures by the super smart Stephan T Lavavej (lead maintainer of Microsoft's STL):
https://channel9.msdn.com/Tags/stephan-t-lavavej
He will convince you the proper way to code in C++ ... I watched these and was amazed at how much the quality of my code improved

Comment: @rmccabe3701: I'll take your word on that and check them out. Thanks a lot for the suggestion, mate. :)

Answer (score 2):

I prefer:

```
std::vector<int> a = {10,10,10,10,10};
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to tell you that my instructor doesn't encourage the use of vectors for some reason and really prefers if I do it using the 'new' keyword.

Comment: So, is it even possible to do what I asked?

Comment: @rmccabe3701: that can be simplified to `std::vector<int> a(5, 10);`, which is also more in tune with being able to specify the count at runtime: `std::vector<int> a(count, 10);`

Comment: @SoutheeRocks: Then your instructor is not embracing what C++ is all about. You should get a new instructor who knows what he is doing.

Comment: @RemyLebeau:  you are right, but doing this always confuses me given C++11's new "braced initializer" syntax.  For example i could do std::vector<int> a{5,10} or std::vector<int> a(5,10),  these two ways of doing things are supposed to be interchangeable --- except for this case ... grrr.  With the braced initializer it creates a vector two elements: 5 and 10.

Comment: @SoutheeRocks: you accepted this as the answer, but this does not answer the question you asked.

Comment: Haha, well, to be fair, he's the instructor of this course called "Data Structures and Algorithms in C++". I don't have the power of getting a new instructor, unfortunately.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Oh, I thought it was a thanks button and not accept button.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with g++ 4.8.2.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   int* a = new int[5]{10, 10, 10, 10, 10};
   for ( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i )
   {
      std::cout << a[i] << " ";
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
10 10 10 10 10
```

**Update, in response to OP's comment**

When you use

```
std::vector<int> v(5, 10);
```

the constructor of `std::vector` used is:

```
vector( size_type count,
        const T& value,
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

Let's say you have a class

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
       MyClass(int ) {}
};
```

You can construct a `std::vector<MyClass>` using:

```
std::vector<MyClass> v(10, MyClass(50));
```

or

```
std::vector<MyClass> v(10, 50);
```

In the second case, the compiler knows how to implicitly construct a temporary `MyClass` object given the argument `50` alone. But either way, a temporary `MyClass` object is being passed to the `vector`, and that is OK because the argument type of that parameter is `const MyClass&`, which can bind to a temporary object.

Comment: Ok, one issue here. What you said is great and thanks a lot for that. But the whole point of me going for dynamic memory allocation is because the size was unknown during compile time. So, suppose, we need to read input of the size during run time from the console and then create the array and initialize all the values to some value, then would it still be possible? Sorry for not being clear, my bad.

Comment: @SoutheeRocks, I don't think you can use the braced-init-list to initialize all the elements when the size is not known.

Comment: @SoutheeRocks: If you have to use `new[]`, then no, there is no opportunity to specify the initial value in the same statement as the allocation. You would have to use `std::fill()` separately (if not a manual loop). Otherwise, switch to `std::vector()`, which has a constructor for specifying the count and initial value, exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Ok, how about this then? I want to create an array of user defined class objects using the vector. Now, how do I pass the constructor arguments when declaring the vector? I'm trying to see how your suggestion to use vector fits my problem.

Comment: @SoutheeRocks, `std::vector<MyClass> a(10, MyClass(50));`  will construct a `std::vector<MyClass>` with 10 elements each of which is initialized by the object returned from calling `MyClass(50)`.

Comment: Oh yes, silly me. That solves my problem. Thank you everyone for your ideas. This was very informative. Love this site.

Comment: @SoutheeRocks: unless the `MyClass` constructor is declared as `explicit`, you can replace `MyClass(10)` with just `10` and C++ will implicitly call `MyClass(10)` for you since the second parameter of that `std::vector` constructor is a `const MyClass&`.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is a very complex language, with many different (even contradicting) goals.

One of the ideas behind it was that you should not pay in efficiency what you don't need and this is what is behind the concept of uninitialized values.

When you write

```
int x;
```

the variable `x` is initialized if it's at global/namespace scope and instead is not initialized when the definition is in a local scope.

This happens not because who designed C is crazy (of course an initialized value is better) but because initialization at global/namespace scope is **free** from an efficiency point of view as it's done compile/link/loading time, not at runtime.

Initializing a variable in local scope instead has a cost (small, but non-zero) and C++ inherited from C the idea that shouldn't pay for it if you don't need it, thus if you want your variable initialized to any value simply says so with:

```
int x = 42;
```

Note however that an uninitialized variable is not simply "containing a garbage value", it's uninitialized and you are not allowed to read its content as such an operation is "undefined behavior".

There are platforms in which just reading the content of an uninitialized variable may crash ("trap representations": for example hardware with dedicated registers for pointers in which just placing an invalid address in a register - not doing anything with it - provokes an hardware exception).

Comment: This really belongs as a separate question and answer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: "But someone told me that if they are declared as global variables, then they are initialized to default values like in Java...is that true as well? Why?"

Comment: Because C++ language standard dictates that behavior is required for global variables.  Not so with local variables.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: most C++ crazy rules have at least a pale and questionable reason behind them. While it's true that "why" it's a stupid question one shouldn't ask (as any answer can be followed with "ok, but why?" ... http://youtu.be/7q89tdSjE-0 ) yet sometimes it's important to know the idea behind an apparently crazy choice because it helps building the logical framework in which other choices can fit. This is hard with C++ because different conflicting ideas are behind it, but knowing the ideas can help a bit. At least helps remembering them...

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to allocate an array with `new[]` and specify an initial value for the array elements.  You have to fill in the array after the allocation is finished, eg:

```
int count = 5;
int* a = new int[count]; 
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    a[i] = 10;
...
delete[] a;
```

That is not very C++-ish.  You could use `std::fill()` to get rid of the loop, at least:

```
int count = 5;
int* a = new int[count]; 
std::fill(a, a+count, 10);
...
delete[] a;
```

A better option is to switch to a `std::vector` instead, which has a constructor that does exactly what you are looking for:

```
std::vector<int> a(5, 10); // create 5 elements initialized to value 10
```

Comment: Yeah, spot on. I really need to check out some tutorials on vectors tomorrow. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector` has a constructor where you can specify the initial size and initial value:

```
std::vector<int> an_array(size, init_value);
```

If you want to use a dynamic array using `new[]`, you have to assign the initial value to each element:

```
int* array = new a[size];

for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    array[i] = init_value;

...

delete[] array;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::array` if the size is known at compile-time:

```
std::array<int, 5> myArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Which is RAII-conform and safe.
You just have to include `<array>` and `<initializer_list>`.
In other cases, use `std::vector`.

Comment: The OP clearly said (even emphasized it): "the array size will only be known at **run time**".  Also, `std::array` is new in C++11.